# postInvalidate() causes heap

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have set up a system to move certain images in an application, but my `postInvalidate()` calls seem to cause a lot of heap space.

```
private class update extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() - prevTime;
        prevTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        speed += (speedIncrease / 5 * timestamp);
        location.y += (int) (speed / 5 * timestamp);
        if (location.y >= targetY) {
            location.y = targetY;
            falling = false;
            super.cancel();
        }
        screen.redraw();
    }
}
```

is my code, being called by a `timer.schedule` once every five milliseconds. The `screen.redraw()` calls a `postInvalidate()` in the view.

A piece of the errorlog I am getting:

```
05-27 07:53:05.711: I/dalvikvm-heap(9805): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.875MB for 1536016-byte allocation
05-27 07:53:05.791: D/dalvikvm(9805): GC_CONCURRENT freed 12K, 21% free 8978K/11335K, paused 2ms+12ms
05-27 07:53:05.861: D/dalvikvm(9805): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1501K, 34% free 7490K/11335K, paused 19ms
05-27 07:53:05.861: I/dalvikvm-heap(9805): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.875MB for 1536016-byte allocation
05-27 07:53:05.941: D/dalvikvm(9805): GC_CONCURRENT freed 12K, 21% free 8978K/11335K, paused 2ms+2ms
05-27 07:53:06.011: D/dalvikvm(9805): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1501K, 34% free 7490K/11335K, paused 19ms
05-27 07:53:06.011: I/dalvikvm-heap(9805): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.875MB for 1536016-byte allocation
05-27 07:53:06.111: D/dalvikvm(9805): GC_CONCURRENT freed 12K, 21% free 8978K/11335K, paused 2ms+3ms
05-27 07:53:06.221: D/dalvikvm(9805): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1502K, 34% free 7490K/11335K, paused 19ms
```

I am not sure what I am missing/doing wrong here. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Edit:

I found the problem already, I accidentally loaded the background in the draw method. The code I've shown here caused the draw method to get called, and therefore the image to get loaded over and over again.

Comment: got any big resource that You attached to your canvas? Big bitmaps will cause this problem....

Comment: I found the problem already, I accidentally loaded the background in the draw method. The code I've shown here caused the draw method to get called, and therefore the image to get loaded over and over again.